# How to avoid blocking main Netty thread when using Ktor Server?

Tags: netty, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm developing a REST API based on Ktor Server running on Netty engine. Let's say I've got two endpoints: one being a simple health check (so it just responds 200 OK), and the other one that makes a long HTTP call in order to respond.

The health check is called every 10 seconds, and the long call takes 20 seconds. The code looks like this:

```kotlin
server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        get("/status/health") {
            call.respondText(status = HttpStatusCode.OK) { "" }
        }
        get("/long-call") {
            val responseBody: MyResponse = client.veryLongCall()
            call.respond(responseBody)
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, the long call seems to be blocking the main thread, meaning the health check is also unresponsive. But while waiting for the long-call response, my server should be able to simply respond to a health check.

I tried marking `veryLongCall()` function as suspend function and running it within `launch {}` or `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block, but it didn't help.

How can I handle these requests in a non-blocking manner?

Please find the example code for reproducing the issue [here](https://github.com/dominikbrandon/ktor-netty-blocking-issue).

Comment: Could you please describe the behavior of the `client.veryLongCall()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem when a request to `https://httpbin.org/delay/100` is made within `veryLongCall`.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. I've just prepared and attached the example code to my original post. My original runtime environment has only 1 CPU, so I needed to additionally configure Netty's group sizes in order for it to correspond better with my case.

Comment: Actually, thanks to that simplified example, I was able to fix blocking the main thread by making use of `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}`. I'll try to port this solution to my real issue again and determine why it didn't help earlier. Do you think it's generally advised to wrap blocking HTTP calls with that clause?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Good, thanks for your help. I have just ported this solution back to my application and it looks to be working fine. Earlier it seemed like it didn't because of bad timing. I was making a long request just a moment before calling a health check, and because it was the first request after application's startup, it was doing some initialization, which drains CPU and takes some extra time, and the health check just times out. If I make the request sometime sooner, the init is already done and my app is able to respond to a health check even though it's still waiting for the long-call's response.

Answer (score 1):

So basically I was wrong in saying that `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` doesn't work. It seemed so because of my specific setup, but I gave it a deeper try and it appeared to be working just fine, meaning it avoids blocking the main thread. Try for yourself using the example code linked in the question.

I have even prepared a test case for that, similar to this one (please note it uses Kotlin, Kotest and Rest Assured):

```kotlin
val longResponses: Deferred<List<Response>> = async {
    (0..4).map {
        async(context = Dispatchers.IO) { longRequest() }
    }.awaitAll()
}
continually(2.seconds, 100.milliseconds.fixed()) {
    val response: Response = given().get("/status/health")
    response.statusCode shouldBe 200
    response.then().time(lessThan(200), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
longResponses.await().forEach { it.statusCode shouldBe 200 }
```